# Handling questions that don't have an easy way to say no

Tags: friends, awkward-situations, saying-no

Let's say you have some friends that tend to ask you for things without giving an easy way out. For instance,

- Hey I'm coming to your house now and picking up your PS4.
- Pick me up for the concert when you are ready.
- (At my house) Let's eat. What all do you have?

In these kind of situations, saying no looks cheap. How do you handle this without confrontation?

Comment: This may help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggestive_question

Comment: Note that the first two are not questions to begin with. They are (implicit) commands, phrased as a statement of fact. That is _incredibly_ arrogant and such a dynamic between you and your friends is not healthy. (The third one is grammatically a question, but it again implicitly states that you will provide food, as a matter of fact)

Answer (score 9):

*Without giving an easy way out.* That's your brain tricking you. Actually you can say no. **Stop feeling guilty if you need to say no.** I'm still learning at this, too!

You should worry less about looking cheap and more about your boundaries. A good friend need to accept boundaries and not be offended by them.

Start your refusal with "sorry" and you're fine.

> Sorry, I can't let you do that.
>   Sorry, I can't do that for you.

If they asking for the reason, just answer honestly. However, if you don't want to give reason:

> Sorry, I just rather not.

And they should respect that.

As a joke: the real answer to the question "How to handle that without confrontation" is *by giving in to their request.* I'm sure you don't want to do that, so learn to be assertive in your refusal.

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution that can apply to a variety of similiar cases is to follow this formula:

> I know that you want to [x], but [y]. I suggest [z].

For example,

> I know that you really want to pick up my PS4, but I can't right now. We can try another time, does tomorrow evening work for you instead?

You have indicated that it is important to you that things don't sound too confrontational. Showing that you hear your friend's concerns and being the first to suggest a compromise is a good way to make things feel less confrontational and to reach a mutually satisfactory resolution.

Finally, it is good to remember that you can always say no.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. One of my concerns was that I don't want to have to give a reason to say no, and this doesn't. What happens if they ask why in this case though?

Comment: @Glyde "Are you sure you want to know why?" *Yes* "It's *my* PS4. You can't just come and pick it up."

Answer (score 3):

### Negative, Ghost Rider, the pattern is full

By being a pop-culture reference, it lightens the message.   Other than being dated, this particular one is fantastic because it applies to a frivolous and somewhat unreasonable request and is a reasonable hard-no.

After the chuckle, if needed you explain why it doesn't work for you.

Try to work out whether his request is unreasonable or your resistance is.   Not with him.

If he is just inherently unreasonable, on an ongoing basis, he may be using you. Distance from him.  There are plenty of friends in the sea.

Answer (score -1):

No easy way out?

"Hey I'm coming to your house now and picking up your PS4."
No, you're not. The PS4 stays at my house.

"Pick me up for the concert when you are ready." Why do you think I was going to pick you up? You could have told me a week ago, I had no idea you wanted to go to the concert. You're on your own.

"(At my house) Let's eat. What all do you have?" Sorry, mate, but the last time you were eating here you left a total mess and left me to clean up. You can eat somewhere else.

There's always an easy way out: Just say NO. It doesn't reduce the amount of confrontation to zero, but as close to zero as possible while getting your way. So what if your "friend" comes up with additional arguments that support their case, why they should get the PS4, be picked up, or eat at your home? You can say something like "That is an excellent argument. The answer is NO". See, minimal confrontation. It's your decision to make. You don't have to listen to their arguments.

Comment: I've definitely seen people do that but I somehow can't get myself to do that. Seems too rude, but I guess it's okay to do so. It does get tricky though when you consider each other good friends, but have different boundaries.

Comment: This seems like the most confrontational way possible to deal with these scenarios, short of being outright hostile.  Not saying that a confrontational style isn't occasionally totally appropriate when people are taking advantage, but the OP specifically looks for a non-confrontational way of handling it.